# Permutations in Java without using an array

Tags: java, permutation

The code below loops through all of the characters submitted, puts them into a string array and then after hashing them, checks against the hashed password originally entered. This logic works fine for up to 5 character passwords however when I get to 6 characters the number of permutations (36^6) is so large that a memory exception is thrown due to the size of the array being too large.

I am therefore trying to modify it too use just string rather than an array to stop this memory issue but cant quite get it to work, any obvious suggestions?

Comment: What about backtracking?

Comment: Don't `getAllPasswords`. Instead, `forEachPermutation` do your check.

Comment: BTW, you are not looking at permutations but at a product, which should make it much easier to build a password-iterator. Just count the number from 0 to infinity and convert them to "base-36".

Comment: Am I not already doing that? Doing the check after each and if the if is satisfied the programs ends

Comment: Anyone able to show me a code example of an alternative to my getAllPasswords function I could take? Would help me to better understand due to being a novice with Java.

Comment: @Unknown In a way, yes, you are doing this, although the method is _very_ weird, returning a list of "permutation" only if the hash is not found and otherwise exiting the program. But for checking 6-character passwords you still store all the 60,466,176 5-character-passwords in memory, which is still a lot.

Comment: @tobias_k  Do you have a method you could show me that doesn't involving the excessive memory storage as that is my issue that I am trying to rectify?

Comment: @Unknown both tobias' and my answer should do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just enumerate all the possible passwords containing letters and digits by counting from 0 to infinity and converting the number [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString-long-int-) with base 36.

```
long k = 0;
while (true) {
    String pwd = Long.toString(k++, 36);
    if (SHA1(pwd).equals(hashedPassword)) {
        System.out.println(pwd);
    }
}
```

Here, `toString` works for a base up to 36, using `[0-9a-z]`, i.e. it works in your case, but if you want to include special characters you will have to create your own number-to-password function (think division and modulo), but the rest remains the same.

This way, the memory requirement is O(1), but of course the complexity is still O(36<sup>n</sup>) for passwords with up to n characters.

---

One problem with this approach is that -- as with all representations of numbers -- leading zeros will be omitted, thus `Long.toString` will never produce a password starting with `0` (except `0` itself).  To counter this, you could use two nested loops -- the outer loop iterating the number of digits in the password and the inner loop iterating the numbers up to 36<sup>d</sup> and padding the string with leading zeros, or loop from 36<sup>d</sup> to 2*36<sup>d</sup> and cut away the first (non-zero) digit. This may seem like a lot more work than before, but in fact it just produces twice as many passwords.

```
for (int d = 1; d < 3; d++) {
    long p = pow(36, d);
    for (long n = p; n < 2 * p; n++) {
        String pwd = Long.toString(n, 36).substring(1);
        System.out.println(n + " " + pwd);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
...
z
00
01
...
zz
```

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: I noticed that that using this while loop it has missed one example password I have used, '00if00'. Doesn't seem to loop through all the possibilities for 0, is there an adjustment I can make to make it do that?

Comment: For example the readout goes:0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
1a
1b
1c
1d
1e
1f
1g
1h
1i
1j
1k
1l
1m
1n
1o
1p
1q
1r
1s
1t
1u
1v
1w
1x
1y
1z
20
21
22

Comment: y z 10 -> after z I was expecting it would go to 00, 01, 02 instead it begins at 1. Is there a way around this as I say a password such as "00if00" will never be found?

Comment: @Unknown Well, that's a side effect of using base-36 numbers. Leading zeros are omitted. But you can still use the enumeration-approach, you'd just have to make your own number-to-password function, as you'd have to do for special characters.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tobias' answer.

Here's a way you can use your *specified alphabet* to recurse through all possible combinations of it, up to a certain length, and operate on each of them without storing them unless you detect that it is a match.

```
// Depth first combinations
private static void combineRecurse(String base, char[] alphabet, int maxLen,
        Consumer<String> consumer) {
    if (base.length() < maxLen - 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            String newPermutation = base + alphabet[i];
            consumer.accept(newPermutation);
            combineRecurse(newPermutation, alphabet, maxLen, consumer);
        }
    } else {
        // the new permutiation will be the maxlength
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            consumer.accept(base + alphabet[i]);
        }
    }
}

public static void forEachCombination(char[] alphabet, int maxLen, Consumer<String> consumer) {
    if(alphabet == null || consumer == null || maxLen < 1) return;
    combineRecurse("", alphabet, maxLen, consumer);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] alphabet = { ... };
    final String hashedPassword = SHA1(password);
    final int maxlen = 16;

    List<String> possiblePasswords = new ArrayList<>();
    forEachCombination(alphabet, maxlen, s -> {
        // System.out.println(s);
        if (SHA1(s).equals(hashedPassword)) {
            possiblePasswords.add(s);
        }
    });
}
```

Making this iterative rather than recursive might be better, but for now the recursive is easy to implement and is probably more easily understandable for a beginner.